# Java Class and Object

Tags: java

I have created two classes: defined and user_defined and two object ob1 and ob2 respectively

```
 class defined {
     int ia;
 }

 class user_defined{
     void user( ){   
        int a=carry;   
        System.out.print(a);
     }

     public static void main(String args[]){         
         int carry;       
         defined ob1=new defined();
         user_defined ob2=new user_defined();    
         obj.ia=10;                                      
         carry=obj.ia;           
         obj1.user();  
     }     
 }
```

I get the output if I print CARRY in the main method. But I want it to get printed by calling a method `user()`, so my question is how can a instance variable of one class can be printed in the method of other class?

Comment: Pass the desired object reference as argument to the method of the other class.

Comment: What is going on with your indentation? Did your keyboard explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually from the example that you provided I can see that you don't understand concept of object programming and even concept of functions. So please, start from begining.

And if you want to print carry variable in method `user()` then you must change this method like this:

```
void user(int a)
{
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

and then in main program you will do something like this:

```
ob2.user(some_int_number);
```

Also, in java, first letter of class names is capital leter. So class names would be Defined and UserDefined. This is just a good practice.

But yeah, start with basics

Answer (score 0):

You could pass carry into void user:

```
class user_defined{
   void user(int carry){   
      int a=carry;   
      System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

And in the main method:

```
obj1.user(carry);
```

Comment: Why did you create new local variable just for printing it out? Can't you just say `System.out.print(carry);`?

Comment: Yes, and that would be more efficient. I was trying to change the least amount of code as possible so that OP would have a better understanding.